# How to fix the error in python pybliometrics.scopus.exception.Scopus401Error?

Tags: pybliometrics

I'm new to pybliometrics. I opened the python pybliometrics documentation and ran this example:

```
from pybliometrics.scopus import AffiliationSearch
query = "AFFIL(Max Planck Institute for Innovation and Competition Munich)"
s = AffiliationSearch(query)
print(s)
```

But it throws a pybliometrics.scopus.exception.Scopus401Error error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Professional/PycharmProjects/firstScopus/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    s = AffiliationSearch(query)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\PycharmProjects\firstScopus\venv\lib\site-packages\pybliometrics\scopus\affiliation_search.py", line 106, in __init__
    Search.__init__(self, query=query, api="AffiliationSearch",
  File "C:\Users\Professional\PycharmProjects\firstScopus\venv\lib\site-packages\pybliometrics\scopus\superclasses\search.py", line 76, in __init__
    Base.__init__(self, qfile, refresh, params=params, url=SEARCH_URL[api],
  File "C:\Users\Professional\PycharmProjects\firstScopus\venv\lib\site-packages\pybliometrics\scopus\superclasses\base.py", line 70, in __init__
    resp = get_content(url, params, *args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\PycharmProjects\firstScopus\venv\lib\site-packages\pybliometrics\scopus\utils\get_content.py", line 88, in get_content
    raise errors[resp.status_code](reason)
pybliometrics.scopus.exception.Scopus401Error

Process finished with exit code 1
```

As I understand it, I need to specify the API keys. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, according to https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/access.html#error-messages 401 is most likely due to a missing key.

As [the documentation on the configuration](https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html) states, pybliometrics starts a process in the beginning to create the config. It asks for the API keys, and more. It seems you skipped this.

To manually create the config, go to your home directory (`~/` on *nix systems) and create the folder `.scopus` (the dot is important). In there, create the file `config.ini` with a normal text editor. It needs to have at least those two sections, Directories and Authentication as shown on the [documentation on the configuration](https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html).

Or simply reinstall pybliometrics and don't skip the set-up prompt in the beginning.